# Why i cant use acos function

Tags: excel

I have a problem with this function. Excel return **#name error**.

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-B3)) * COS(RADIANS(90-$G$3)) + SIN(RADIANS(90-B3)) * SIN(RADIANS(90-$G$3)) * COS(RADIANS(C3-$G$4))) * 6371
```

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: It works for me in Excel 2010

Comment: office 365 @BigBen

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, works fine for me in office 365.

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/BW8A @BigBen

Comment: My guess is one of the cells you are referencing has the #Name error, have you stepped through your formula?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/RvDw
Do you think this? @NathanSutherland

Comment: It looks like you need to use `ARCCOS` from [this page](https://www.excel-function-translation.com/index.php?page=english-czech.html)?